# Extract substrings from a column of strings and place them in a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-regex

I have the following data frame:

```
   a    b             x  
0  id1  abc 123 tr    2  
1  id2  abd1 124 tr   6 
2  id3  abce 126 af   9 
3  id4  abe 128 nm    12
```

From column b, for each item, I need to extract the substrings before the first space. Hence, I need the following result:

```
list_of_strings = [abc, abd1, abce, abe]
```

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex with `^\S+` (non-space characters anchored to the start of string) and [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['b'].str.extract(r'^(\S+)', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
0     abc
1    abd1
2    abce
3     abe
Name: b, dtype: object
```

For a list:

```
list_of_strings = df['b'].str.extract(r'^(\S+)', expand=False).tolist()
# ['abc', 'abd1', 'abce', 'abe']
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R4BgiT/1)